# savefig does not save plots in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using pycharm to program in Python. I wanted to save my figures as png without plotting them, thus I had used the following matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, when I tried to save the figures using the following code, though no error is generated,  non of the figures are saved and destination folder remains empty

```
j = 0
count = 1
fileNameTemplate = r'C:\Python\Results\tempTR\Figure{0:02d}.png'
for k, vD1 in landmarks.items():
    img1 = cv2.imread(k, 0)
    col_0 = vD1[:, 0]
    col_1 = vD1[:, 1]
    fd = predict_training_labels[j]
    j += 1
    D1 = fd[0:18]
    D2 = fd[18:36]
    denorm_0 = D1 * Ymax
    denorm_1 = D2 * Xmax
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.imshow(img1, origin='lower', cmap='gray')
    plt.scatter(vD1[:, 0], vD1[:, 1])
    plt.scatter(denorm_0, denorm_1)
    plt.title(k)
    for i in range(0, 18):
        plt.annotate(str(i + 1), (vD1[i, 0], vD1[i, 1]))
        plt.annotate(str(i + 1), (denorm_0[i], denorm_1[i]))
    fig.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
    count += 1
    plt.close(fig)
```

Minimal code for the problem is given below:

```
count=1 
fileNameTemplate = r'C:\Python\Results\Norm\TempTR\Figure{0:02d}.png'  
vD1= [[1391., 3468.], [1070., 3384.], [ 890., 3288.], [ 777., 3133.], [ 606., 
2908.], [1454., 2979.], [ 999., 3012.], [ 548., 2716.], [ 489., 2519.], [ 
686., 1696.], [ 769., 961.], [1049., 681.], [1287., 957.], [1275., 1366.], 
[1016., 1838.], [1016., 2219.], [1408., 2457.], [1525., 2695.]]
col_0 = np.array(vD1)[:, 0]
col_1 = np.array(vD1) [:, 1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.scatter(np.array(vD1) [:, 0], np.array(vD1) [:, 1])
for i in range(0, 18):
        plt.annotate(str(i + 1), (np.array(vD1)[i, 0], np.array(vD1)[i, 1]))
fig.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
plt.close(fig)
```

Can you advise me please on this issue

Comment: Does "landmarks" array contain any elements? Can you provide a sample of what it contains?

Comment: Hi Teoretic, Yes it does here an examples of its elements:
 '445B.jpg': array([[1391., 3468.],        [1070., 3384.],        [ 890., 3288.],        [ 777., 3133.],        [ 606., 2908.],        [1454., 2979.],        [ 999., 3012.],        [ 548., 2716.],        [ 489., 2519.],        [ 686., 1696.],        [ 769.,  961.],        [1049.,  681.],        [1287.,  957.],        [1275., 1366.],        [1016., 1838.],        [1016., 2219.],        [1408., 2457.],        [1525., 2695.]], dtype=float32)}

Comment: thank you, I will take a look

Comment: Unfortunately, "predict_training_labels", "Ymax", "Xmax" are not defined in your code, please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you want to run the code, then you can the minimal example in the next comment, the problem I have is with saving the figures in Pycharm. I had run the code on Spyder and I know that it does work fine. Yet I cannot save the figures in Pycharm

Comment: Part I
count=1 
fileNameTemplate = r'C:\Python\Results\Norm\TempTR\Figure{0:02d}.png'  
vD1= [[1391., 3468.], [1070., 3384.], [ 890., 3288.], [ 777., 3133.], [ 606., 2908.], [1454., 2979.], [ 999., 3012.], [ 548., 2716.], [ 489., 2519.], [ 686., 1696.], [ 769., 961.], [1049., 681.], [1287., 957.], [1275., 1366.], [1016., 1838.], [1016., 2219.], [1408., 2457.], [1525., 2695.]]
col_0 = np.array(vD1)[:, 0]

Comment: Part II
col_1 = np.array(vD1) [:, 1]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.scatter(np.array(vD1) [:, 0], np.array(vD1) [:, 1])
for i in range(0, 18):
        plt.annotate(str(i + 1), (np.array(vD1)[i, 0], np.array(vD1)[i, 1]))
fig.savefig(fileNameTemplate.format(count), format='png')
plt.close(fig)

Comment: please post the minimal code in the question itself for better formatting and completeness

Comment: Please see above the edit version of the question

Comment: You minimal code worked in my PyCharm 2018.1.3 Community, I changed "fileNameTemplate" to point to the current directory `fileNameTemplate = r'.\Figure{0:02d}.png'`. It saved me a picture file into my project directory.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, I am using pycharm professional 2017 3.3

Comment: Please post the version of your installed matplotlib, maybe there's a problem in some version of matplotlib

Comment: The matplotlib version I am using is 2.2.2

Comment: I have the same version, the problem is somewhere else then

Comment: I am running the code on an external GPU server, I can get the predictions values from it but not the figures, not sure where the problem lies exactly. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do you seek for the generated image in the filesystem of the server you're running code on, or in the filesystem of your local machine?

Comment: The folder is on my local machine

Comment: You execute your code, if I understood correctly, on the server - I suggest you to check if the picture is being saved into the filesystem of the server. Maybe that's why you don't see any errors - your code "correctly" saves an image, just into the filesystem of the server.

Comment: If that was the case then saving the results on the fileNameTemplate = r'.\Figure{0:02d}.png' should have solved the problem, since the results will be saved on the same directory of the program. But as has been mentioned before, this didn't solve the problem.